# How to turn COMBIN() function into an arrayformula in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've tried turning this one:

`=if(B6="";"";combin((D6+(F6+1));(F6+1))*((F6+1)/(D6+(F6+1)))^(F6+1)*(((D6+(F6+1))-(F6+1))/(D6+(F6+1)))^((D6+(F6+1))-(F6+1)))`

by doing it like this:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(if(B6:B="";"";combin((D6:D+(F6:F+1));(F6:F+1))*((F6:F+1)/(D6:D+(F6:F+1)))^(F6:F+1)*(((D6:D+(F6:F+1))-(F6:F+1))/(D6:D+(F6:F+1)))^((D6:D+(F6:F+1))-(F6:F+1)))`

but it keeps giving me the wrong result. What would be the approach here?

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: how can you tell it's a wrong result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you use open ranges like `F6:F`.
In your calculations you have `(F6:F+1)`. This will keep expanding for ever.

Try closing the ranges using a **maximum** number which would be your **existing rows minus one**.
Like if you sheet has 888 rows try the maximum `F6:F887`